# При первом запуске dcoker-compose появляется ошибка liqubase, но со второго запуска приложение запускается без ошибок

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, liquibase

При первом запуске `docker-compose up --build`  приложение падает со следующей ошибкой

`Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.`

Но при втором запуске, приложение запускается нормально

Мой docker-compose :

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  client-backend:
    image: notes:0.0.1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT= 8085
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres/notes_bd

  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:14.1'
    ports:
    - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=postgres'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234'
      - 'POSTGRES_DB=notes_bd'
    volumes:
      - ./infrastructure/db/drop_db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/drop_db.sql
      - ./infrastructure/db/create_db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_db.sql
```

Полный лог запуска с ошибкой:

```
 Network notes_default             Created                                                                    0.1s 
 ✔ Container notes-postgres-1        Created                                                                    0.8s 
 ✔ Container notes-client-backend-1  Created                                                                    1.8s 
Attaching to client-backend-1, postgres-1
postgres-1        | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgres-1        | This user must also own the server process.
postgres-1        | 
postgres-1        | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgres-1        | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgres-1        | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgres-1        | 
postgres-1        | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgres-1        | 
postgres-1        | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
postgres-1        | creating subdirectories ... ok
postgres-1        | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
postgres-1        | selecting default max_connections ... 100
postgres-1        | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
postgres-1        | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
postgres-1        | creating configuration files ... ok
postgres-1        | running bootstrap script ... ok
postgres-1        | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
postgres-1        | syncing data to disk ... ok
postgres-1        | 
postgres-1        | 
postgres-1        | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgres-1        | 
postgres-1        |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
postgres-1        | 
postgres-1        | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
postgres-1        | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
postgres-1        | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
postgres-1        | waiting for server to start....2024-02-13 13:02:26.726 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgres-1        | 2024-02-13 13:02:26.730 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres-1        | 2024-02-13 13:02:26.870 UTC [49] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-02-13 13:02:23 UTC
postgres-1        | 2024-02-13 13:02:26.893 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres-1        |  done
postgres-1        | server started
postgres-1        | CREATE DATABASE
postgres-1        | 
postgres-1        | 
postgres-1        | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_db.sql
postgres-1        | psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_db.sql: error: could not read from input file: Is a directory
postgres-1 exited with code 1
client-backend-1  | 
client-backend-1  |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
client-backend-1  |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
client-backend-1  | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
client-backend-1  |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
client-backend-1  |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
client-backend-1  |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
client-backend-1  |  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.2)
client-backend-1  | 
client-backend-1  | 2024-02-13T13:02:31.142Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.danillkucheruk.notes.NotesApplication  : Starting NotesApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.10 with PID 1 (/app/*.jar started by root in /app)        
client-backend-1  | 2024-02-13T13:02:31.175Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.danillkucheruk.notes.NotesApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
client-backend-1  | 2024-02-13T13:02:42.206Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
client-backend-1  | 2024-02-13T13:02:42.620Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 374 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
client-backend-1  | 2024-02-13T13:02:47.997Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8085 (http)
client-backend-1  | 2024-02-13T13:02:48.095Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
client-backend-1  | 2024-02-13T13:02:48.096Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.18]
client-backend-1  | 2024-02-13T13:02:48.396Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
client-backend-1  | 2024-02-13T13:02:48.400Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 16224 ms
client-backend-1  | 2024-02-13T13:02:55.024Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
client-backend-1  | 2024-02-13T13:02:55.042Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
client-backend-1  | 2024-02-13T13:02:55.220Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :
client-backend-1  | 
client-backend-1  | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
client-backend-1  | 2024-02-13T13:02:55.370Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
client-backend-1  | 
client-backend-1  | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
client-backend-1  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar!/:6.1.3]
client-backend-1  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar!/:6.1.3]
client-backend-1  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar!/:6.1.3]
client-backend-1  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar!/:6.1.3]
client-backend-1  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar!/:6.1.3]
client-backend-1  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar!/:6.1.3]
client-backend-1  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar!/:6.1.3]
client-backend-1  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar!/:6.1.3]
client-backend-1  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar!/:6.1.3]
client-backend-1  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1231) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar!/:6.1.3]
client-backend-1  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:949) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar!/:6.1.3]
client-backend-1  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar!/:6.1.3]
client-backend-1  |     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar!/:3.2.2]
```